# How do I prove $F_{n+1}^2 - F_nF_{n+2} = (-1)^n$ using induction?

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

$F_n$ refers to the $n$ term of the Fibonacci Sequence.

I think I'm supposed to prove this by induction. I already have the base case. I am at:
$\text{F}_\text{k+1}^2 - F_k\text{F}_\text{k+2}  + \text{F}_\text{k+2}^2 - \text{F}_\text{k+1}\text{F}_\text{k+3} =  (-1)^k +\text{F}_\text{k+2}^2 - \text{F}_\text{k+1}\text{F}_\text{k+3}$

So it's probably easier to work backwards. Multiply $-1$ in order to get $(-1)^\text{k + 1}$  and then get:

$-\text{F}_\text{k+1}^2 + F_k\text{F}_\text{k+2}  - \text{F}_\text{k+2}^2 + \text{F}_\text{k+1}\text{F}_\text{k+3} =  (-1)^\text{k+1} -\text{F}_\text{k+2}^2 + \text{F}_\text{k+1}\text{F}_\text{k+3}$

So then bring everything to the left side and mess around with the left side.

$-\text{F}_\text{k+1}^2 + F_k\text{F}_\text{k+2}  - \text{F}_\text{k+2}^2 + \text{F}_\text{k+1}\text{F}_\text{k+3} +\text{F}_\text{k+2}^2 - \text{F}_\text{k+1}\text{F}_\text{k+3} =  (-1)^\text{k + 1} $

And so somehow get this to look more like this:
$\text{F}_\text{k+1}^2 - F_k\text{F}_\text{k+2}  + \text{F}_\text{k+2}^2 - \text{F}_\text{k+1}\text{F}_\text{k+3}$

...except I don't know how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Are you by any chance refering to Fibonacci's sequence?

Comment: You neglected to mention that $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number. For that is what it is,right?

Comment: Oh yeah. sorry about that

Comment: yep Is a duplicate of the link you provided @HaraldHanche-Olsen

Comment: my bad, sorry about that.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606204/fibonacci-proof-question

Answer (score 3):

Hint
\begin{align}
F_{n+1}^2-F_nF_{n+2} &= F_{n+1}^2-(F_{n+2}-F_{n+1})F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}^2-F_{n+2}^2+F_{n+1}F_{n+2} \\ &=F_{n+1}(F_{n+1}+F_{n+2})-F_{n+2}^2=F_{n+1}F_{n+3}-F_{n+2}^2.
\end{align}