# Show that $f_{n+1}\cdot f_{n-1}-f^2_n=(-1)^n$ if $f_n $ is the $n$th Fibonacci number

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

I've reviewed this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/606286/584468 and I'm getting lost on how he did $f_{k+2}f_k−f^2_{k+1}=(f_k−f_{k+1})f_k−f^2_{k+1}$

When I thought that $f_{k+2}=f_{k+1}+f_k$?

But I'm getting:

$$(f_{k+1}+f_k)\cdot f_k-f^2_{k+1} = f_{k+1}\cdot f_k +f^2_k - f^2_{k+1}$$
$$=(f_{k+1})(f_k-f_{k+1}) + f^2_k$$
$$=(f_{k+1})(f_k-(f_k+f_{k-1})) + f^2_k $$
$$=f_{k+1}\cdot(-f_{k-1}) + f^2_k$$
$$=-f_{k+1}\cdot f_{k-1} + f^2_k$$
$$=(-1)(f_{k+1}\cdot f_{k-1} - f^2_k)$$
$$=(-1)(-1)^k$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. The linked answer is in error; it's using the reverse Fibonacci recurrence $f_{k+1}+f_k=f_{k-1}$ consistently, and not noticing that this isn't quite the same as the original.